# In linux is it possible to extend a ramdisk with a physcial drive in a logical volume?

Tags: lvm, ramdisk, tmpfs

I do not like how tmpfs behaves with swap and will allow memory to be exhausted before using the swap on physical disk (yes swappiness can be adjusted but it's still affecting the rest of the OS by exhausting resources).

Instead I would like to create a dynamic ramdisk with a defined upper limit that is then extended into a physical drive via the concept of a logical volume.

ie. `/tmphybrid` =  `0-512mb ram` + `0-2048mb harddrive`

Possible? Possible with ramdisk being dynamic and not completely allocated to start with?

Comment: How precisely would this differ from just using a HDD and letting the OS cache things? (The only thing I can think of is preloading the RAM drive with files).

Comment: This question has already been answered. 


http://superuser.com/questions/255060/how-can-i-change-the-amount-and-size-of-linux-ramdisks-dev-ram0-dev-ram15