# Ramdisk size - kernel config or boot parameters?

Tags: linux, boot, ramdisk

I need to use a ramdisk to mount a filesystem <strike>as a ramfs</strike> on an embedded device. However, this requires me to increase the size of the ramdisk - currently as per the kernel config, maximum size is 35MB. I can modify boot parameters, but recompiling the kernel may not be possible.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/255060/how-can-i-change-the-amount-and-size-of-linux-ramdisks-dev-ram0-dev-ram15) question that addressed ramdisk creation. However, I am unsure as to whether **both** `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE` and the boot parameter <strike>`ramdisk=`</strike> `ramdisk_size=` need to be changed. Would I be able to create a ramdisk of size, say 40MB by just changing the <strike>`ramdisk=`</strike> `ramdisk_size=` boot parameter?

**EDIT** : If it helps, [this](https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/RootFileSystemOnARamdisk) describes the ramdisk I'm trying to get up and running.

Comment: Linux "ramfs" and "tmpfs" aren't ramdisk-based, and not even blockdev-based (they're backed by page cache and dynamically sized). Are you using ramfs _or_ ramdisk?

Comment: @grawity I'm using a ramdisk. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either Kconfig or a boot-time option works. However, the option name is not `ramdisk=` anymore. According to [Documentation/blockdev/ramdisk.txt](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/blockdev/ramdisk.txt#L39), you can change the size using either:

- the `ramdisk_size=` option, or
- the `brd.rd_size=` option.

In [drivers/block/brd.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/block/brd.c#L330):

```
unsigned long rd_size = CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE;
module_param(rd_size, ulong, 0444);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(rd_size, "Size of each RAM disk in kbytes.");

[...]

/* Legacy boot options - nonmodular */
static int __init ramdisk_size(char *str)
{
    rd_size = simple_strtol(str, NULL, 0);
    return 1;
}
__setup("ramdisk_size=", ramdisk_size);
```

You can see that the Kconfig value is merely used to initialize the *rd_size* variable, and either `brd.rd_size=40960` or `ramdisk_size=40960` would completely override it and set the size to 40 MB.

Comment: Thanks @grawity, I'll try it out. One of the reasons I had this doubt, was that I was getting a couple of errors with just the boot parameter. Maybe I didn't allocate enough memory.